# Creation of library functions

Tags: c

I have created a library functions in C.. which will be accessed by the user , through a User interface application. Now I need to create a independent module which will be used by library functions . And when I call any library functions.. new function ( independent module) also should run in parallel or Concurrently​.

Comment: Had a look at `alarm()` already?

Comment: I am using clock function from time.h , I want timer in micro seconds or milliseconds.

Comment: If on POSIX you might like to have look at `timer_create()` & Friends

Comment: Sure. Thank you. I will look into it.. if I call this timer function from my lib function. Will both run in parallel?

Comment: "*Will both run in parallel?*" I hope so ... ;-) Docs are here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html and here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/timer_create.3p.html

Comment: What does the timer module need to time?  What is it going to do?  Measure how long code runs?  Measure the response time of the user to UI events? Interrupt your program after a period of time has elapsed?  Do these repeatedly?  How is the timer module going to be configured?  Is it going to be mandatory, or optional?

Comment: For example I want to execute a function X , when function X is invoked... Along with it...A timer also should start..And both function X and timer should run in parallel and end..And result of function x is seen..If it's successful or not. Timer is mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to write portable library for UI applcation. It dependes upon OS and UI framework.

Posix timer(timer_create) is per process timer. It may not compatible with your UI framework or other library. I would suggest to utlize UI framework because most of modern UI framework is event driven which has built in timer with (mostly) milliseconds resolution. Timer callback is called in (main) thread which mainloop runs on.

I can imagine two approach.

1. write timer lib for each UI framework
   You may add new implementation of same interface whenever you met a new UI framework. I'll bet you only need one or two.
2. write timer lib with dependency inversion interface. 
   You can design timer API with set of callbacks such as one_shot_timer_start_callback, periodic_timer_start_callback and etc. Design intention is that app has responsiblity to initialize lib with these callbacks. 
   You may provide sample callback set for each UI framework.

In both case, you must initialize lib with UI framework context (or View).

Comment: Thank you :) it's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alarm()` to trigger `SIGALRM` signal and set `SIGALRM` handler using `signal()` prior to calling `alarm()`.

Signal handler will be called after specified number of seconds are elapsed

You can use `ualarm` in case you need timers at microsecond level

Edit: As mentioned by @alk `ualarm` it is marked obsolete, you can use time_create family functions, to create and set timers